# If statement in Dart?

Tags: html, google-maps, dart

So Im working on a project using the google maps API in Dart, but I am running into a bit of a problem I don't really know exactly how to fix. the problem is that I have this If statement:

```
   if (querySelector("#input") == "202") {
      final location = (new InfoWindow(new InfoWindowOptions())
          ..position = new LatLng(40.316002, -76.034599)
          ..content = 'room 202'
      );
    }
```

The Functionality of the if statement is pretty self-explanatory(its using Google maps for Dart) but I cant seem to get it to that. here is the html part:

```
 <form><p id="rly">
Enter room number</p><br>
<input type="text" id="input">
</form>
```

Any advise or Ideas? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your question is not entirly clear to me but this line very probably doesn't do what you expect

```dart
if (querySelector("#input") == "202") {
```

`querySelector("#input")` returns the `Element` with the id `input`. An element never equals to `202`. Maybe you mean

```dart
if ((querySelector("#input") as InputElement).value == "202") {
```

Comment: I replaced my if statement with that but I'm starting to think the problem is my input method, take a look at this http://prntscr.com/5715i3

Comment: I don't know what I am supposed to see at the screenshot.

Comment: look at the url, the input box, and the map. it still did not work and I cant seem to find out why.

Comment: I haven't used Google maps myself yet. Maybe someone else has an idea.

Comment: I even added these: http://i.imgur.com/tmFoNpe.png          ans it still doesnt work :I

Comment: Have you tried to use the debugger to see which if is actually entered? You can also add `print(xxx)` statements to get feedback what the code does.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer what is the `as` operator?

Comment: It is like casting and helps with code completion and avoid static warnings. `querySelector` returns an `Element` but an `Element` doesn't have a `value` field but `InputElement` has and because we know `querySelector('#input')` returns an `InputElement` we can add this as a type hint.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately you have not provided quite enough code to indicate what is happening. Based on what you have provided, it does not look like you're binding any changes in input element, or any submissions from the form. Your screenshot in the other answer's comment also suggests this as it appears your form is being fully submitted.

Where is the code for your if check located? Are you using any packages like Polymer or Angular? (They can help with data/event binding). However assuming you're not, you'll need to setup an event listener. In this case we'll put it on the form element as that way it will only run the code when we hit enter in the input field (or a submit button if we had it). First some changes to your HTML to add an ID to the form:

```html
<form id="numForm"><p id="rly">
Enter room number</p><br>
<input type="text" id="input">
</form>
```

Now to bind it in our main() method once the page loads:

```dart
main() {
  // ...
  // Whatever other code you have

  // This sends any 'submit' events on the form to the updateMap method.
  querySelector('#numForm').onSubmit.listen(updateMap);
}

void updateMap(Event e) {
  var num = (querySelector('#input') as InputElement).value;
  if(num == '202') {
    // .. Same as before, assuming the Google Maps stuff is right
  }
}
```